# Force key as row entry when Parsing Json to Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON object structured as follows (from the [Braze API](https://www.braze.com/docs/api/endpoints/export/canvas/get_canvas_analytics/#parameters)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "name_of_canvas",
    "stats": [
      {
        "time": "2019-01-01",
        "total_stats": {
          "revenue": 0.0,
          "conversions": 123,
          "conversions_by_entry_time": 456,
          "entries": 1234
        },
        "step_stats": {
          "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000": {
            "name": "step_name",
            "revenue": 0.0,
            "conversions": 12,
            "conversions_by_entry_time": 34,
            "messages": {
              "email": [
                {
                  "sent": 100,
                  "opens": 50,
                  "unique_opens": 48,
                  "clicks": 18,
                }
              ],
            }
          },
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  "message": "success
}
```

I want to parse it into a Pandas dataframe, structured as follows:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'time', 'total_stats.revenue', 'total_stats.conversions', 
'total_stats.conversions_by_entry_time', 'total_stats.entries', 'step_stats.step_id', 'step_stats.name', 'step_stats.revenue', 
'step_stats.conversions', 'step_stats.conversions_by_entry_time', 'step_stats.messages.email.sent', 'step_stats.messages.email.opens', 'step_stats.messages.email.unique_opens', 'step_stats.messages.email.clicks'])
```

Critically, the `'step_stats.step_id'` column should contain the API identifier for the step as a *row entry*, rather than each step being split out into individual columns per step_id.

I have tried using a recursive function to flatten the object, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698215/how-to-parse-deeply-nested-json-to-pandas-dataframe), however this results in the step_id being included in the column name rather than as a row entry.

I have also spent some time playing with `pd.io.json.json_normalize`. The closest I have to the desired output is:

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(
    data=dict_object['data']['stats'],
    meta='name')
```

But the step_id is still incorporated as part of column names:

```
  ... step_stats.00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000.revenue| step_stats.00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000.conversions| step_stats.00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000.conversions_by_entry_time| step_stats.00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000.conversions1| step_stats.00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000.conversions1_by_entry_time ...
```

Is there any way to force pandas to interpret a key as a row entry in a database?

Secondarily, is the above structure (specifically using a uuid as a key) good practice when structuring JSON objects? I'd like to know more out of curiosity than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved! I needed the `step_id` to be preserved at the same level within the JSON object as it existed when it was a key, because it was a unique identifier for the `step_stats` information.

I wrote a recursive function (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698215/how-to-parse-deeply-nested-json-to-pandas-dataframe)) which creates a new param `step_id` at the correct level of the hierarchy:

```
def is_valid_uuid(val):
    try:
        uuid.UUID(str(val))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def extract_keys(obj):
    """Pull all keys from nested JSON."""
    arr = []
    new_obj = {}

    def extract(obj):
        """Recursively search for keys in JSON tree."""
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            for k, v in obj.items():
                if isinstance(v, (dict)):
                    if is_valid_uuid(k) == False and k != 'step_stats' and k != 'total_stats':
                        new_obj[k] = v


                    elif is_valid_uuid(k) == True:
                        sub_obj = {}
                        # define a new key, value pair, setting new value to old key
                        key, value = 'step_id', k
                        sub_obj[key] = value
                        #rename old key
                        sub_obj['step_stats'] = v
                        arr.append(sub_obj)

                elif isinstance(v, list):
                    for i in v:
                        extract(i)
                extract(v)

        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for item in obj:
                extract(item)
        return new_obj


    results = extract(obj)
    del new_obj['data']['step_stats']
    new_obj['data']['steps'] = arr 
    return results
```

The output of which looks as follows:

```
{'data': {'name': 'canvas_name',
  'total_stats': {'revenue': 0.0,
   'conversions': 123,
   'conversions1': 456,
   'conversions2': 789,
   'conversions3': 901,
   'conversions_by_entry_time': 234,
   'conversions1_by_entry_time': 567,
   'conversions2_by_entry_time': 678,
   'conversions3_by_entry_time': 901,
   'entries': 234},
  'step_stats': [{'step_id': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'step_stats_stats': {'name': 'Step Name',
     'revenue': 0.0,
     'conversions': 17,
     'conversions1': 59,
     'conversions2': 31,
     'conversions3': 28,
     'conversions_by_entry_time': 19,
     'conversions1_by_entry_time': 15,
     'conversions2_by_entry_time': 31,
     'conversions3_by_entry_time': 20,
     'messages': {'webhook': [{'sent': 984, 'unique_recipients': 194}]}}},
   {'step_id': '0000000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'step_stats_stats': {'name': 'step name',
     'revenue': 0.0,
     'conversions': 942,
     'conversions1': 819,
     'conversions2': 1195,
     'conversions3': 177,
     'conversions_by_entry_time': 62,
     'conversions1_by_entry_time': 879,
     'conversions2_by_entry_time': 595,
     'conversions3_by_entry_time': 077,
     'messages': {'webhook': [{'sent': 339, 'unique_recipients': 379}]}}}]}}
```

Note that `step_stats` is now a list, rather than a dictionary in the structure and that `step_id` and `step_stats_stats` are contained within a dictionary, each of which is an element of the `step_stats` list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is a pretty badly formatted json. I am not sure that the native interpreter will ever consider a key; a value in a json. what I would do if you know for sure the structure of your file, is to extract the value and add it as extra parameter.
When you read the json just with the library it'd look something like this:

```
b = json.loads(a) # Where a maps to an object you outlined above (starting with 'data')
api = list(b.get('data', {}).get('stats', [])[0].get('step_stats', {}).keys())[0]
```

A bit of explanation here, the .get function helps you to set up additional params so if there is no data filled, or stats field and so it will return an empty dict, list and so on, kind of error handling but you'd need to extend it.

Then it is up to you to decide where you add it. I'd have an extra field - and go

```
b['data']['api_name'] = api
```

Then pandas will be able to interpret it as a separate column.

*Just minor comment please text real JSON with dummy data whatever if you put a lot of and here comes more data... and things like that it will become difficult for everyone to debug your code and work with the data you uploaded

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have updated the JSON to contain dummy data. Am attempting to implement your solution now.